# Why WCF service is set as SOAP

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, wcf, soap

[image]

I have created the WCF service mentioned above when testing it using the Microsoft WCF Test Client and trying to invoke one of the methods, the response is "ERROR 400 Bad Request".
Also, the type of the service is shown as SOAP (Check the image) why? Is this the default of WCF or what?

The service contract:

```
  [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetPatientNameByID(string ID);

    [OperationContract]
    PatientsEnt getClass();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate ="AddNewBank",Method ="POST",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool AddNewBank(BanksEnt bank);

    [OperationContract]
    List<BanksEnt> GetBanksList();
    // TODO: Add your service operations here   

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "ValidateRel/RelationNumber={RelationNumber}/CallID={CallID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string ValidateRel(string RelationNumber, string CallID);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    string testSer();



}
```

Service1.svc

```
   public bool AddNewBank(BanksEnt ent)
    {
        try
        {
            return     BanksBiz.AddNewBank(ent);              

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
    public List<BanksEnt> GetBanksList()
    {
        try
        {
            return BanksBiz.GetBanksList();


        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            // File.AppendAllText("log.txt",ex.Message);
            throw;// ex;
        }

    }

    public string ValidateRel(string RelationNumber, string CallID)
    {
        return "hello";
    }

    public PatientsEnt getClass()
    {
        return null;
    }


    public string testSer()
    {
        return "test-1 service";
    }
```

Endpoint configuration in the client

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="soapService" sendTimeout="00:05:00" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://www.example.net/cms/Service1.svc/soap"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soapService"
                contract="IService1" name="soapService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How is the endpoint configured, did you set the correct binding and behaviors?

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: it looks like you instructed it to act as a soap service so why do you expect it to act as a non-soap service?

Comment: You need to have a ServiceEndpoint with the WebHttpBehavior. Please read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service). Given the amount of questions you have about wcf you might consider to follow some basic tutorials first to grasp the idea behind endpoints, bindings and contracts.

Comment: Consider not to reveal you endpoint address as one step to protect the web service from DoS attack

Comment: @HassanShouman because your endpoint is using a SOAP config binding "basicHttpBinding".

Answer (score 1):

Because your endpoint is using a SOAP binding protocols "**basicHttpBinding**". There are 2 main binding protocols in WCF for SOAP Web Service:

- ***BasicHttpBinding*** for SOAP 1.1
- and ***WsHttpBinding*** for SOAP 1.2 and WS-Addressing specification.

The major differences you must have noticed is the security aspect, where by default, **BasicHttpBinding** sends data in plain text while **WsHttpBinding** sends it in an encrypted and secured manner.

**Otherwise for REST service, this is MSDN remark**

The WCF Web Programming Model allows developers to expose WCF Web services through HTTP requests that use "plain old XML" (POX) style messaging instead of SOAP-based messaging. For clients to communicate with a service using HTTP requests, an endpoint of the service must be configured with the  that has the  attached to it.